# Lazy initialization for objects that initializing by reflection

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

I have my own attribute `[Finder]` for fields and properties, and I have a kind of factory that initializing all fields and properties as I want.
Question:
I want to do kind of lazy initialization(object be created only when I calling some methods of this object) for objects that i'm initializing.
Note: properties and fields could be different types.

Comment: What does your factory do with the `Finder` attribute?

Comment: it just extracting 2 fields from it(selectors) that helps to find html elements on web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the initialization happens, you can use the new [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) type. Another possibility would be to return a automatically created subclass of your class - a proxy - that checks the state of the initialization at every method call and executed the initialization if necessary.

Comment: Lazy whan't do the job, can u offer some library that will create proxy for me?

Comment: sorry but can u offer something else, coz castle didn't match my needs&

Comment: Problem solved, but problem was that, I needed to create proxy for class that have non virtual methods that needed to be intercepted!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to make use of [System.Lazy<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx). Otherwise, you'll have to implement logic to keep track of what properties/fields have been initialized yourself.